# compileDebugKotlin failure with null-safe in MapController.kt

Tags: flutter, kotlin, here-api

I'm using HereMaps SDK for my project and trying to pull it up into this one. While starting a debugging, i'm getting an error with MapController.kt

```
\android\src\main\kotlin\com\here\mapview\MapController.kt: (52, 41): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Activity?
```

Comment: please include you code too.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Sweeper f (plugin.registrar != null) {
            plugin.registrar?.activity().application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
        } else {
            // if already attached to activity, register
            activity = plugin.activityBinding?.getActivity()
            activity?.application?.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
        }

this is the place where the error drops from

Comment: @eamirho3ein 

void _onMapCreated(HereMapController hereMapController) {
   hereMapController.mapScene.loadSceneForMapScheme(MapScheme.normalDay,
        (MapError? error) {

      const double distanceToEarthInMeters = 8000;
      final MapMeasure mapMeasureZoom =
          MapMeasure(MapMeasureKind.distance, distanceToEarthInMeters);
      hereMapController.camera.lookAtPointWithMeasure(
        GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915),
        mapMeasureZoom,
      );
    });
  }

Comment: Closing this issue because of HERE SDK is not compatible with Flutter 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Flutter 3 is not supported by HERE SDK, for more help please refer to the minimum requirements at https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.12.4.0/dev_guide/topics/about.html#minimum-requirements.

The minimum supported Flutter version is 2.8.0. The latest stable Flutter version that works with the HERE SDK is 2.10.5.

~MS